# How can I boot the PC-BSD live DVD-ISO IMAGE directly via GRUB2?

Tags: boot, freebsd, grub2, boot-loader

Via the [loopback](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#loopback) command, GRUB2 allows to directly boot an ISO file.

Now, I've configured the according *menuentry* to boot the PC-BSD **[Live DVD ISO](http://www.pcbsd.org/get-it/download-pc-bsd-isotope)**, but when I try to boot it, the *FreeBSD bootstrap loader* outputs:

```
can't load 'kernel'
```

**Here is the GRUB2 menuentry I currently use:**

```
menuentry "PC-BSD" {
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set root 0d11c28a-7186-43b9-ae33-b4bd351c60ad
        loopback loop /PCBSD9.0-RC1-x64-DVD-live.iso
        kfreebsd (loop)/boot/loader
}
```

**Does one know how I'd need to amend that in order to be able to boot the PC-BSD live system?**

Answer (score 1):

After "can't load 'kernel'" you get dropped to the loader prompt.

It has an `ls` command, so you can check where your kernel is and load it with `load` and then `boot`.

Also you can try to boot the kernel directly, by trying something like `kfreebsd (loop)/boot/kernel/kernel`.

Comment: Little late, but I just saw your answer. `ls` gives `open '/' failed: no such file or directory`. I wonder how the loader works while (apparently) no root is found?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to chainload the bootloader on your image. grub2 chainloading works like this:

```
insmod chain
set root = (hdX,Y)
chainloader +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: as someone noted in [this thread](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/19701/), the issue is that the boot process at some point wants to mount the root filesystem from the loopback device in a way that is not possible with GRUB's loopback functionality. Note that PC-BSD was renamed to [TrueOS](https://www.trueos.org/) and that they now offer USB images.

---

I'm not too familiar with BSD and I can't find anything about BSD in Arch's [Multiboot USB drive article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive), however they have 3 ways in their [GRUB article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#FreeBSD_menu_entry), at least one should work when adapted to loop-mounted devices:

> Chainloading the embedded boot record
>
> ```
> menuentry 'FreeBSD' {
>   insmod ufs2
>   set root='hd0,gpt4,bsd1'
>   chainloader +1
> }
> ```

This seems to be simple and loading the appropriate filesystem module appears to be a good idea but but remember that on optical media there is ISO 9660 or UDF and there are no partitions to my knowledge but El Torito.

> Running the traditional BSD 2nd stage loader
>
> ```
> menuentry 'FreeBSD' {
>   insmod ufs2
>   set root='(hd0,4)'
>   kfreebsd /boot/loader
> }
> ```

That's almost what you did just as a static configuration without calling search.

> Loading the kernel directly
>
> ```
> menuentry 'FreeBSD' {
>   insmod ufs2
>   set root='hd0,gpt4,bsd1'
>   ## or 'hd0,msdos4,bsd1', if using an IBM-PC (MS-DOS) style partition table
>   kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
>   kfreebsd_loadenv /boot/device.hints
>   set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom=ufs:/dev/ada0s4a
>   set kFreeBSD.vfs.root.mountfrom.options=rw
> }
> ```

That looks surprisingly complex. I just tarted downloading the PC-BSD 10.3 iso, hopefully I find some time playing with it to figure out how to make it work via UEFI or legacy in the next few days.