# How to run PC-BSD iso from GRUB with only Linux installed

Tags: freebsd, grub2, iso, bsd

I'm working on Ubuntu, and I wanted to try BSD. I downloaded a PC-BSD iso (PCBSD9.2-RELEASE-x64-DVD-USB-latest.iso). I wanted to know if it is possible to use "loopback" to run that image even if I have no BSD kernel installed. Here is my `40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec tail -n +3 $0

# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "PCBSD" {

      insmod loopback

      echo Loadind...

      set isofile="/PCBSD.iso"

      loopback loop (hd0,2)$isofile
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What you have so far looks sufficient to establish the loopback, but not enough to actually load and boot the image.  --  Have you tried any experiments from the Grub command line?  For example, what happens when you try the commands shown here?  Do you see a listing of files within the ISO?  http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/loopback.html#loopback

Comment: Oh, also:  What version of Grub are you using?

Comment: I have the 1.99 GRUB version, I red somewhere it might work with 1.97 and greather, right?

I'm trying the "ls loop". I'll let you know the result.
If I understand, this is a simple way to know the kernel path, isn't it?

By the way, is there a way to emulate grub loopback command under Unix-like (actually linux)?

Comment: the loop is correctly established, I've undestood "kernel" command is "linux" on my grub, but when I specify the iso kernel path, grub returns me "bad magic number". It makes sense if kernel and linux commands are not the same... Any idea?

Comment: I suspect (but have not confirmed) that the `linux` command makes certain assumptions about the kernel image layout that are not true for a BSD kernel.  As such, I would experiment with chainloading the boot block from the ISO image.

Comment: I didn't thought it was possible :o
Does it mean something like : chainloader(loop)+1?

Comment: What about if you create a grub entry like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/how-can-i-boot-the-pc-bsd-live-dvd-iso-image-directly-via-grub2   ? Cheers :)

Comment: I also red that topic, but it seems I don't have the kfreebsd module on my grub version. For the moment I abort this way, I'm already burning the iso...

Answer (score 3):

I initially thought this was feasible.  Upon reflection, I no longer think so.

Grub is frighteningly capable, and can dive into just about any filesystem and pull files out.  So Grub will have no difficulty fishing the kernel out of the ISO image.

However, once Grub hands off control to the loaded kernel, *Grub's involvement ends*, and whatever code Grub branched to is now wholly responsible for doing the rest of the work.  This means the BSD kernel would need to understand that the rootfs is not sitting on a bare block device or CD-ROM disc, but rather inside a file living on an ext[234]-formatted disk partition.  While this is technically possible, the kernel being booted needs to be explicitly set up for this.  I seriously doubt this is the case with the BSD kernel in your ISO image.  Even if Grub were to somehow leave behind a BIOS-level I/O device (*highly* doubtful), BSD would eventually want to start initializing its own device drivers to replace it, at which point things would fall over.

So no, I'm pretty sure it won't work.  Your alternative is either writing the ISO to a disc or a USB key as @Kiwy suggested, or to boot the BSD kernel inside a virtual machine.

ADDENDUM

Even though I'm supposed to be working on something else at the moment, it still bugged me that there are many Web pages out there detailing how to boot an ISO *file*, so I did a little more digging.

Yes, you can boot certain Linux *distros* from an ISO *file*.  Examples illustrating this are done using the Grub `linux` (nee `kernel`) command, whose documentation reads as follows:

> Command: `linux file …`
>
> Load a Linux kernel image from `file`. The rest of the line is passed *verbatim* as the kernel command-line. Any initrd must be
>   reloaded after using this command (see initrd).

[Emphasis mine.]

The Grub examples for booting Ubuntu from an ISO file typically appear as:

```
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
```

So I started looking for the kernel docs for the `iso-scan` argument and discovered...  There aren't any.  `iso-scan` is not a standard Linux command line argument.  Neither is `findiso`, which appears in some other examples.

I eventually happened upon a [Fedora bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=557426) lamenting the inability to boot from an ISO file, whose comments casually mentioned that `find-iso` and its ilk are handled not by the kernel, but by the initramfs.  Googling from there, it becomes apparent that booting from an ISO is handled in a distro-specific manner (Ubuntu does it differently from Fedora, who does it differently from Grml, etc.).

So, *in general*, my answer stands: The kernel won't boot out of an ISO file without help.  Some (many?) Linux distros have done this work.  It is unclear whether the BSD distro you want to test drive has done similar work.  And so, you'll have a much easier time booting in to a virtual machine or, as @Kiwy suggested earlier, off a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks for the vote and the information your post is quiet interesting in fact.

Answer (score 0):

No chance, BDS is a free Unix system and using your linux kernel to boot on the iso is definitely not going to work, why not just download a live bsd from here :
http://livebsd.com/

Burn it or put it on a usb key and boot on it from your bios menu ?

And here a short explanation of why what you're asking for can't work :
http://www.over-yonder.net/~fullermd/rants/bsd4linux/03

*Edit 1:*
If you want to try freeBSD from a live CD lunched from grub then you need to add the corrct grub entry that contains at least the line :

```
kernel /path/to/iso/kernel
```

That indicates the path to the kernel on the iso.

But in My opninion you should use the bios menu to boot onto a live cd or usb key instead of trying to but from grub because at each different cd you want to try you will have to change your grub.

Comment: He's not asking to boot BSD from Linux; he's asking to boot a BSD ISO from Grub.

Comment: Well in that that case use the bios to boot on live cd is a solution as the iso he tries to use is an installation only iso according to the name he gives.

Comment: I noted it was not a "universal" solution, I thought it might be good to know. Otherwise, seems kernel command is not recognised by my grub (1.99 vesion)

Comment: In fact, kernel function has been replaced by "linux". But when I did linux /path/to/iso/kernel, grub returns me "bad magic number". This is annoying... Any idea?

Comment: anyway thanks for the 2 down votes I'm trying to help someone with offering a possibility it's maybe not the one expected but it is what it is. @kirly I do not know what is the the path in your case but it is unlikely `/path/to/iso/kernel`  and something like `/boot/kernel` but I don't know bsd tha much. concerning the unkwo kernel command I can't help you I'm no specialist in grub at all...

Comment: and here a great tuto about boting onto iso from grub https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot for linux but I guess it's adaptable

Comment: it's precisely what I've tried yesterday, the only trouble is that you can't load a bsd kernel with linux command, it needs "kernel" command (which is not recognised by my grub version). Finally I think I'll abort that idea, too complicated to work with grub and its missing modules. Anyway thanks for your help, and sorry for the down votes you received :/

Comment: yep no problem just that I found them pretty unfair as they are not off topic completly

Comment: Downvote removed; see my answer.